# Powershell- Write-Output not working within 'else'

Tags: powershell, if-statement

So, I'm new to powershell, so just bear with me here.

I'm using powershell to create a  command prompt, and most of it, is just functions, and if statments, when i try to use a 'else' statement, with 'Write-Output', it leaves a blank new line, heres my code;

```
while ($true) {
$Title = "Falcon Os v1 alpha cli"
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $Title
$global:current_path=Get-Location
$global:current_path=$global:current_path.Path
$starterterminalpromptone = $current_path
$starterterminalprompttwo = " >>> "
$prompt = $starterterminalpromptone + ". Type 'sys.win.man.help' for help " + $starterterminalprompttwo
Write-Host $prompt -NoNewLine
$command = $Host.UI.ReadLine()
if ($command -eq "sys.win.info.nl") {sys.win.info.nl}
if ($command -eq "sys.win.man.help") {sys.win.man.help}
if ($command -eq "sys.command.output.out.echo.command.variable") {sys.command.output.out.echo.command.variable}
if ($command -eq "sys.exit") {break}
if ($command -eq "sys.path.cd") {sys.path.cd}
if ($command -eq "sys.path.view") {sys.path.view}
if ($command -eq "sys.screen.cls") {cls}
if ($command -eq "sys.path.mkdir") {sys.path.mkdir}
if ($command -eq "sys.path.makefile") {sys.path.makefile}
if ($command -eq "sys.win.cleartext.vtext.show") {sys.win.cleartext.vtext.show}
elseif ($cs -eq "start"){Write-Output ""}
elseif($cs -eq "command"){Write-Output ""}
else {Write-Output "Unknown command."}
}
```

By the way, all my if statemnts lead to mostly functionns, but made it the only part i need.

What it does when i put a unknown command, it simply leaves a blank new line.

I use powershel 7.20, and use ISE to edit my code.

Comment: If it leaves a new line it's most likely because it's entering one of the `elseif` conditions. What is `$cs` ? I don't see that var being defined on your script.

Comment: Have a look at [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch), which can make your code better readable than using all those if's

Comment: $cs is a variable that holds the current state it's in, for example: if i type a command, it will set $cs accordingly. and i think i should just be able to remove `write-output""` it probably could just be nothing.

Comment: The issue with your code is that you're using `if` > `elseif` > `else` only with the last `if` statement instead of a chain of `if` > `elseif` statements. In addition to that, `$cs` is never defined as a variable on your code.

Comment: It Is defined, earlier in the code, it sets the stage it's in, so it wouldn't  be reacting to everything.